# MongoDB Remove object key based on value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my application, I have a MongoDB document that will be updated with `$inc` operation to increase/decrease the number in `appliesTo` object. Here is a sample object

```
{
  name: "test-document",
  appliesTo: {
    profiles: {
      Profile1: 3,
      Profile2: 1
    },
    tags: {
      Tag1: 7,
      Tag2: 1
    }
  }
}
```

After I'm running the following command

```
await db.items.updateOne({name: "test-document"}, {$inc: {'appliesTo.profiles.Profile2': -1})
```

my document will be changed to

```
{
  name: "test-document",
  appliesTo: {
    profiles: {
      Profile1: 3,
      Profile2: 0
    },
    tags: {
      Tag1: 7,
      Tag2: 1
    }
  }
}
```

I'm struggling with writing a query that will remove all keys, which values are `0`. The only solution I have currently is to iterate over each key and update it using `$unset` command. But this is not an atomic operation

Is there a smarter way to handle it in one query?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do both operations in a single regular update quey, you can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$cond` to check is a key field's value greater than 1 then do `$add` operation otherwise remove it by `$$REMOVE` operator

```
await db.items.updateOne(
  { name: "test-document" },
  [{
    $set: {
      "appliesTo.profiles.Profile2": {
        $cond: [
          { $gt: ["$appliesTo.profiles.Profile2", 1] },
          { $add: ["$appliesTo.profiles.Profile2", -1] }
          "$$REMOVE"
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ao-5wHLZQ-i)